# Deletion of cq node property using curl command

Tags: curl, aem

I want to delete cq node property using following curl command, but it gives 404 error. However, 'test' property is there in the details node.

curl -X DELETE http://localhost:4502/content/test-content/en_US/marketing/data/establishing-multichannel/jcr:content/details/test -u admin:admin

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try posting the property name with the `@Delete` suffix. You don't have to set any value to the posted property:

```
curl -F test@Delete= \
     -u admin:admin \
     http://localhost:4502/content/test-content/en_US/marketing/data/establishing-multichannel/jcr:content/details
```

More info can be found in the [Sling documentation](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#delete).